# Import multiple XML files with similar structure into Access DB with the same table

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access

I researched and got code for importing multiples XML files from a local path to Access Database table.

I intend to add a lagging timer to avoid collision between each XML files if the desktop is too slow to import it.

```vb
Private Sub Command2_Click()

Dim fs
Dim fsFolder
Dim fsFile
Dim i As Double

Set fs = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set fsFolder = fs.getfolder("C:\MyDesiredPath")

For Each fsFile In fsFolder.files
    Debug.Print fsFile.Name
    Application.ImportXML fsFile.Path, acStructureAndData

    i = Timer + 0.5
    While Timer < i
        DoEvents
    Wend
Next fsFile

End Sub
```

From this code, let's say if I have 100 XML files in the share path, it will result in 100 tables in the Database after importing the XML files.

My goal is to get all of these 100 XML files into one table. As they carry the same structure, I think it is possible.

Comment: Importing into an existing table does not seem to be possible with `Application.ImportXML`. How about this: Import with `ImportXML` into a new table, then copy everything from that new table into an existing table and delete the new table again, Repeat for each file, done.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. I will give it a try

Comment: @Tomalak I got the code to delete table. As I am a newbie in MS Access VBA, I would be grateful if you could provide me with the code to copy everything from that new table into an existing table.

Comment: This can be done with a single SQL statement. See [MSDN: INSERT INTO statement (Microsoft Access SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/insert-into-statement-microsoft-access-sql)

Comment: Try acAppendData option.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Import_XML()
    Dim strFile As String       'Filename
    Dim strFileList() As String 'File Array
    Dim intFile As Integer      'File Number
    Dim strPath As String       ' Path to file folder
   
    'strPath = Me![Path]
    strPath = "C:\XML\"
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.XML")
    strFile = Dir(strPath & A)      
    
    While strFile <> ""
       'add files to the list
      intFile = intFile + 1
      ReDim Preserve strFileList(1 To intFile)
      strFileList(intFile) = strFile
      strFile = Dir()
    Wend
    
    'see if any files were found
    If intFile = 0 Then
      MsgBox "No files found"
      Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'cycle through the list of files
    For intFile = 1 To UBound(strFileList)
      Application.ImportXML strPath & strFileList(intFile), 2
    Next intFile
    
    MsgBox "Import Completed"
End Sub
```

Comment: How do I write a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer